# power bi stacked bar chart does not sort correctly

Tags: graph, powerbi, data-visualization

I have a stacked bar chart wit a list of institutions in the Axis, a category as legend and an orders count (measure) for values.

I want to sort the bar chart descending on the counts of orders. However, the desc sort does not work. It returns first all the rows with 0 than it starts by the highest count and descends.

Any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: can you provide sample data for this? you can also add your expected output for the sample data.

Comment: I guess you're using different data in 'values' than in your 'sort'.  My first guess would be that it's sorted alphabetically but you've cut off the first character so we can't see!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 
@mkRabbani 
I cannot provide sample data. When I recreate the data it is working just fine. I am quite sure that this is a small but very particular error. 

I am using direct input from a tabular model on an Azure Analysis Services instance. Hence, it makes it a bit difficult to provide meaningful sample data. 
Thanks anyways though!

Comment: Thanks for your input @JeffUK I am sorting by orders count and descending. I cut off the text intentionally and it is not sorted alphabetically. 


Maybe this might help though:
I have 17 institutions on the y axix. All institutions above the bar in the screenshot have an orders count of 0.
The institution with the long bar has the highest number of counts and from there on the descending sorting works just fine. 

Where I have the problems is, why does Power BI put the institutions with an count of 0 above the institutions with an order count >0. They should be after, because desc.

Comment: If you've done exactly what you describe, it won't sort it the way you're seeing; there must be something else going on that we can't see from your screenshot.  Try setting up a simple example for yourself using e.g. a dummy excel data source and you'll see that.